# Setting up Artifactory and Jenkins behind Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, jenkins

I currently have it that Artifactory can be accessed at `http://localhost:8081/artifactory` and Jenkins can be accessed at `http://localhost:8080/jenkins/`

What I would like is for Jenkins and Artifactory to be accessed via

```
http://localhost/jenkins
http://localhost/artifactory
```

respectively.

Currently this is what the Virtualhosts part of my config looks like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jenkins
    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://localhost:8080/jenkins
    ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://localhost:8080/jenkins
    ErrorLog "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\logs\jenkins-error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\logs\jenkins-access.log" combined

   <Proxy http://localhost:8080/jenkins*>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
     </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName artifactory
    ErrorLog "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\logs\artifactory-error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\logs\artifactory-access.log" combined
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    ProxyPass /artifactory/ http://localhost:8081/artifactory/
    ProxyPassReverse /artifactory/ http://localhost/artifactory/
</VirtualHost>
```

If Jenkins is the first virtualhost then then I can access it on `http://localhost/jenkins` but I cannot access artifactory on `http://localhost/artifactory` and vice versa.

The output of my `Apache.exe -S` is:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server jenkins (C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/conf/httpd.conf:974)
         port 80 namevhost jenkins (C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/conf/httpd.conf:974)
         port 80 namevhost artifactory (C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/conf/httpd.conf:990)
Syntax OK
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should only have one VirtualHost and put both ProxyPass mappings inside it.